# How to get rid of passive voice misuse?

Tags: passive-voice

I know that the following sentence has grammatical error:

*The simulation results of the winglet was provided.*

How can I reframe this sentence correctly?

Comment: How do you know the problem is in the use of the passive voice?

Comment: Several possible ways to remove passive voice, if that is what you want. But they depend on context. For example, if you know that "Bill the technician" did the providing you could say "Bill the technician provided the simulation results of the winglet." So, you need to know who did the providing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that passive voice is the primary problem with the sentence.

- The verb should be "were provided" not "was provided" ("results" is plural).
- "The simulation results of the winglet" sounds awkward. It would be better to say "The results of the winglet simulation" or "The winglet simulation results".
- The sentence feels like it needs more information. The verb "provide" means that something was provided to someone else. Who? For example, you could say, "The results of the winglet simulation were provided to the client." Or in active voice, "The team provided the results of the winglet simulation to the client."